# How to determine scalar-to-tensor ratio r from CMB polarization spectrum?

Tags: cosmology, data-analysis, cosmic-microwave-background

CMB polarization spectrum can tell us about the primordial scalar and tensor perturbation. By analyze B and E mode angular spectrum power spectrum  and temperature power spectrum we can determine the scalar-to-tensor ratio r, as many articles implies.

I know that r is **defined** by the ration of **amplitude** of primordial tensor and scalar perturbation. But what we in fact **measure** is the power spectra. So I wonder how can we get the value of r from the spectra we measure thus we can study the physics of primordial perturbations and inflation.

Comment: Introduction 
The possible detection of tensor perturbations in the
cosmic microwave background (CMB) by the BICEP2
experiment suggests that inflation occurred at a high
energy scale Ei = 2 × 1016 GeV, just two orders
of magnitude below the reduced Planck scale MPl =1/√8πG = 2.4×1018 GeV
This is what I have read in this.
How Many e-Folds Should We Expect from High-Scale Inflation?
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.5538.pdf

Comment: VI. CONCLUSIONS
The recent BICEP2 discovery, if verified, suggests that
high-scale cosmic inflation is the correct theory of the
very early Universe. With characteristic energy of order
1016 GeV, observational signatures of inflation open the
door to physics on the threshold of the Planck scale.
Many models of inflation are currently being investigated
for their ability to fit precision CMB observations. The
current success of relatively simple models of inflation,
driven by a single scalar field with a potential and a
canonical kinetic term

Answer (score 1):

Most of this answer is based on [First-Year Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe (WMAP) Observations: Implications For Inflation](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003ApJS..148..213P/abstract).  As I am not an expert in this area, I am more transcribing the computation rather than interpreting it.

The tensor/scalar ratio is given by:
$$r \equiv \frac{\Delta^{2}_{h}(k_{0})}{\Delta^{2}_{\mathcal{R}}(k_{0})}$$

Where the scalar power spectrum is:
$$\Delta^{2}_{\mathcal{R}}(k) \equiv \frac{k^{3}}{(2\pi^{2})\langle|\mathcal{R}_{k}|^{2}\rangle}$$

and the tensor power spectrum is:
$$\Delta^{2}_{h}(k) \equiv \frac{k^{3}}{(2\pi^{2})\langle|h_{+k}|^{2}+|h_{\times k}|^{2}\rangle}$$

$\mathcal{R}$ is the "curvature perturbation in the comoving gauge"

$h_{+k}$ and $h_{\times k}$ are the "two polarization states of the primordial tensor perturbation"

The spectra are parameterized by:

$$\Delta^{2}_{\mathcal{R}}(k) = \Delta^{2}_{\mathcal{R}}(k_{0}) \left(\frac{k}{k_{0}}\right)^{n_{s}(k_{0})-1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{dn_{s}}{d\ln k}\ln(\frac{k}{k_{0}})}$$

$$\Delta^{2}_{h}(k) = \Delta^{2}_{h}(k_{0}) \left(\frac{k}{k_{0}}\right)^{n_{s}(k_{0})+\frac{1}{2}\frac{dn_{t}}{d\ln k}\ln(\frac{k}{k_{0}})}$$

$\Delta^{2}_{\mathcal{R}}(k_{0})$ and $\Delta^{2}_{h}(k_{0})$ are normalization constants and $k_{0}$ is a "pivot wavenumber."